# Is there a way to invoke a void function in drools?

Tags: drools

Is there a way to invoke a void function as part of the when condition?
I am trying to have my own function which has some business logic that has to be invoked as part of every rule.

eg: custom log functions, this function is static.

```
rule "some rule"
    when
        $instance : Customer(type == "Regular");
        eval(Utils.log());
    then
        ......
end
```

When i execute the above the function gets invoked but the execution fails with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Utils.log() : java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.drools.core.rule.EvalCondition.isAllowed(EvalCondition.java:129)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakEvalNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakEvalNode.java:72)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakEvalNode.doNode(PhreakEvalNode.java:56)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:389)
```

Can someone help throw some light as to how i could invoke a function in the when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a void function from the right hand side. You cannot from the left hand side because it doesn't make any sense. The left hand side are supposed to be conditions -- a void isn't a condition.

```
rule "some rule"
when
  Customer(type == "Regular")
then
  Utils.log()
end
```

Read this as: "When there is a customer with type 'Regular', then call the `log()` function."

Logically, you couldn't do it from the "When". What would that even mean? "When there is a customer with type 'Regular' and ... void?"

---

If you insist on doing it this way, change the return type of your logging function to return `true`, so it will always have a matching condition. **Do not** rely on the results of this logging call to try and track execution time or the rule executing -- all it will tell you is when the Drools engine evaluated the line when it is determining rule matches. If subsequent conditions cause the match to be discarded, the logging will have already fired. Methods in your conditional clause should be pure and have no side effects.

```
public static boolean log() {
  // logic
  return true;
}

rule "an awful rule don't do this"
when
  Customer(type == "Regular")
  Boolean (this == true) from Utils.log()
then
  // logic
end

rule "another awful rule, still don't do this"
when
  Customer( type == "Regular" )
  eval( Utils.log() )
then
  // logic
end
```

**I absolutely *do not* recommend *ever* doing this.**

---

If you're just trying to log rule hits or matches, you should be using a [listener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#engine-event-listeners-con_decision-engine) to implement your logging logic instead of polluting your rules.